# Unable to resolve network-related or instance-specific error

Tags: asp.net, database, connection-string

I'm working on a asp.net application but I did not use it from last 2-3 days and today when I open and run this application Its gives following error-

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details.

what should I do now?

Comment: Check if your SQL Server service has been started.

Comment: Check your SQL Server Management Service short SSMS.exe is running in services

Comment: how to check that its running or not

Comment: TaskManager -> Services or Window -> Run -> Services.msc

Comment: SSMS.exe is not showing in list...........why i'm seeing such error when it was working 3 days ago